# Capture todos to the last Tasks heading

Tags: org-mode

I have such a diary structure

```
*** 2019-07-28 Monday 
**** Tasks
*** 2019-07-29 Tuesday
**** Tasks
```

Desire to capture todos under the Tasks of latest day

```
(setq org-capture-templates '(("t" "Todo [inbox]" entry (file+headline "~/ORG/src/sdiary.org"
                                                                       "Tasks") "* TODO %i%?")
                              ("T" "Tickler" entry (file+headline "~/ORG/src/tickler.org" "Tickler")
                               "* %i%? \n %U")))
```

conversely, it collect todos to the first Tasks not the tasks at the bottom of the file.

How could capture todos to the last tasks rather than the first tasks.

Comment: I don't think that's possible unfortunately. The code for `file+headline` (but for some of the other plausible choices, like `file+regexp`, as well), finds the first occurrence: there is no provision to find the last occurrence. You would have to change the code in the function `org-capture-set-target-location` to do what you want. Have you considered storing your diary in the opposite order (latest time first) instead?

Comment: Have a look at the available options and see if anything there suits your needs (including, but not limited to the properties section ....):  https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filename+function` as described in the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html):

> ‘(file+function "filename" function-finding-location)’
>
> A function to find the right location in the file.

The following function moves the point to the last headline matching `**** Tasks`:

```lisp
(defun my-org-goto-last-tasks-headline ()
  "Move point to the last headline in file matching \"**** Tasks\"."
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (re-search-backward "^\\*\\*\\*\\* Tasks"))
```

Then use this function in your capture template as follows:

```lisp
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "Todo [inbox]" entry
         (file+function "~/ORG/src/sdiary.org"
                        my-org-goto-last-tasks-headline) "* TODO %i%?")
        ("T" "Tickler" entry
         (file+headline "~/ORG/src/tickler.org" "Tickler") "* %i%? \n %U")))
```